# Are there any restrictions on retrieving items while on a hunt?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

As a new feature to Monster Hunter World, it is now possible to access the entire Item Box from any base camp while on a quest. Are there any restrictions on this? Is it possible to keep going back to camp to restock on healing items, traps, and ammo when hunting a particularly difficult monster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked myself the same question and for having tested it, I can answer: no, there's no restrictions, they brought your box with you, and every single possibility you have when you're in your base is the same that what they give you in mission, excepted that the display is different than what you have in your base

Comment: This is mainly because the game almost *want*s players to just go out on an expedition and hunt to their heart's content. instead of going back to base, grabbing a new quest and going through that whole process. You can stay in the world pretty much as long as you want, and only have to go back to Astera for crafting and turn ins.